# Error doing git pull

Tags: git, git-pull

I'm getting suddenly this error when I try to pull changes from repository:

```
git pull
fatal: http://guthub.com/msalsas/BunchOfColors/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

Seems to be a typo ("guthub"), because if I do it in this way:

```
git pull http://github.com/msalsas/BunchOfColors
```

it works. The thing is that I don't know what could cause this problem and how to solve it.
I've been working with this repo before and pulling changes without any problem.

Comment: @Rob - Is it a question? That's what I'm doing: I'm pulling the repository in the server. The repository reference is at http://github.com/msalsas/BunchOfColors

Comment: Should have read this more closely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mostly likely a typo in your remote configuration. Assuming that it's called `origin` (the default), you can fix it with:

```
git remote set-url origin http://github.com/msalsas/BunchOfColors
```

Or fix it by hand by editing the offending line in `.git/config`.

Comment: Thank you. Now it works. Do you know what could have happened? It worked before, and I don't think that I touched it.

Comment: Strange; the only commands that I know of that actually change a remote's url are `remote add` and `remote set-url`, so I'm not sure what else could have changed it. Did you do any manual editing of `.git/config` or run any scripts that did?

Comment: Theoretically I've not changed anything of `.git/config`.